# Steam OpenGl error

Tags: games, steam, opengl

**Computer Specs**

- OS - Ubuntu 15.10
- Cpu - i7 2600
- Gpu - Radeon r7 250x
- HDD - Hitachi 500gb

So just recently I have been getting errors when I open steam:

[image: Error #1 when i open steam]

Then when I try to launch a game (cs:go for example) I get this error:

[image: Error when opening a game]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Dell notebook ?
Have you opened your catalyst and set your graphic bord ?
If is a notebook, i think you are using the Intel graphic card and not the Radeon Graphic card(i resolve my problem open the catalist and set the graphic card -but remeber, you need to re open your system to set)